# Como calcular media de coincidencias en un List en C#

Tags: c#

Partiendo de estas dos clases

```
class Objeto {

        public int IDTipo { get; set; }        
        public float Valor { get; set; }

        public Objeto(int iDTipo, float valor)
        {            
            IDTipo = iDTipo;            
            Valor = valor;
        }

        public Objeto()
        {
        }
    }

class TipoObjeto {
        public int ID { get; set; }        
        public float ValorMedio { get; set; }

        public TipoObjeto(int iD)
        {
            ID = iD;                       
        }
    }
```

El problema es el siguiente, necesito hacer una lectura de dos listas. En una tengo un registro de objetos con las propiedades "ID"(algunos repetidos) y "valor" y la otra List es una recopilacion de Tipos de objetos diferenciados por el ID.

```
static List<Objeto> listaObjetos = new List<Objeto>() {
            new Objeto() { IDTipo=3, Valor=0.4f },
            new Objeto() { IDTipo=2, Valor=0.3f },
            new Objeto() { IDTipo=45, Valor=0.2f },
            new Objeto() { IDTipo=2, Valor=0.1f },
            new Objeto() { IDTipo=45, Valor=0.3f },
        };
static List<TipoObjeto> listaTipos = new List<TipoObjeto>();
```

La otra lista de tipos de objeto la relleno de forma dinámica leyendo la primera mediante este método

```
public void CrearYVisualizarTiposDeObjetos()
        {            
            for (int i = 0; i <listaObjetos.Count;i++) {
                Objeto ObjetoLeido = new Objeto(listaObjetos[i].IDTipo, listaObjetos[i].Valor);

                if (listaTipos.Count == 0)
                {
                    listaTipos.Add(new TipoObjeto(ObjetoLeido.IDTipo, ObjetoLeido.Valor));
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < listaTipos.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (listaTipos[j].ID == listaObjetos[i].IDTipo)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if ((j+1) == listaTipos.Count)
                        {
                            listaTipos.Add(new TipoObjeto(ObjetoLeido.IDTipo));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            

            Console.WriteLine("Listado de tipos ---------------------");
            foreach (var tipoObjetoFinal in listaTipos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tipo: "+tipoObjetoFinal.ID);
            }
        }
```

Ahora lo que necesito es actualizar en la segunda lista la propiedad `public float ValorMedio { get; set; }` la cual me guarda el valor medio del la propiedad de Objeto `public float Valor { get; set; }`

Entiendo que hay que hacer una lectura adelantada de `static List<TipoObjeto> listaTipos = new List<TipoObjeto>();` 
pero estoy atascado. No consigo descubrir como "guardar" en un contador el numero total de coincidencias para hallar la media de los valores de cada Objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes calcular el valor medio con este código:

```
var listaTipos = listaObjetos
            .Select( o => o.IDTipo)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(o => new TipoObjeto(o){
            ValorMedio = listaObjetos.Where(o1 => o1.IDTipo == o).Average(o1 => o1.Valor)
    });
```